# Make subset of dataframe by filtering on time stamp column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, that has a datetime64[ns] timestamp column, and a few other columns with it.
I am trying to filter the dataframe so that i only work with a specific time from all the times in there. (for eg i only 10:10  from the below eg)
I tried looking at the at_time or between_time methods, but i guess they only work with a specific date range ?
ALso tried df['timestamp'].dt.time == "10:10:00" , but fails

```
timestamp              Col1 Col2  Col3 
2021-01-01 10:00:00 
2021-01-01 10:10:00 
2021-01-01 10:20:00
```

Can you advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

since your column 'timestamp' is of dtype `datetime` so you have to provide `datetime.time()` for comparision because `df['timestamp'].dt.time` is giving you time which is of `datetime.time` dtype

```
import datetime

m=df['timestamp'].dt.time == datetime.time(10,10)
#OR
m=df['timestamp'].dt.time == pd.Timestamp("10:10:00").time()
#OR
m=df['timestamp'].dt.time == pd.to_datetime("10:10:00").time()
```

Finally:

```
result=df[m]
```

output of `m`:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: timestamp, dtype: bool
```

Comment: m=df['timestamp'].dt.time == pd.Timestamp("10:10:00").time() worked